# How does react js ensure immutability of props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return <h1>Hello, {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Welcome name="Sara"/>;
```

I have this in jsx.

It compiles to this js:

```
function Welcome(props) {
  return __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createElement(
    "h1",
    {
      __source: {
        fileName: _jsxFileName,
        lineNumber: 7
      },
      __self: this
    },
    "Hello, ",
    props.name
  );
}

var element = __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createElement(Welcome, { name: "Sara", __source: {
    fileName: _jsxFileName,
    lineNumber: 10
  },
  __self: this
});
```

It looks like normal js to me.

[image]

So I put a break point here in chrome.

When it ran to that break point, I went to chrome's console and did this:
[image]

These 3 expressions were typed into the console and executed when the break point was on.

It seems like I really can not change properties of the variable named props.

But the props object looks like an innocent object, how is this implemented in react js?

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Is each one of those console logs from where the break point is? It's hard to tell as there isn't enough detail, but I'd guess it's not immutable (that doesn't make sense to me) it's probably just getting reset higher up the call stack

Comment: @Liam all three expressions were executed when the break point was on

Comment: `props` are read-only.

Comment: I think the question is how is this achieved?

Comment: @Dan yes, I understand it is made immutable, my question is how is its immutability ensured by react js

Comment: @Liam yes, I am curious about the how

Comment: When you change your `prop` via the console, you're not executing Welcome's `render()` function. The function is executed when a parent component modifies the `prop` values.

Comment: @Dan, I don't quite get it. this expression "props.name='blah'" was executed in the console, then when I evaluate this expression "props", I still get the name "Sara" back. what made this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5c6a496d98b80d19d851c2ec3a56d760b7118a50/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L161:L170)

> ```
> // Two elements created in two different places should be considered
> // equal for testing purposes and therefore we hide it from enumeration.
> Object.defineProperty(element, '_source', {
>   configurable: false,
>   enumerable: false,
>   writable: false,
>   value: source,
> });
> if (Object.freeze) {
>   Object.freeze(element.props);
>   Object.freeze(element);
> }
> ```

The `props` are created using [Object.defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) which gives you and ability to set `writable: false` and then "freezing" it with [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

> The Object.freeze() method freezes an object: that is, prevents new
>   properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from
>   being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their
>   enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed. 
>   The method returns the object in a frozen state.

JSFiddle brief example (open the console before running): https://jsfiddle.net/rttw629v/

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/5c6a496d98b80d19d851c2ec3a56d760b7118a50/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L168

Comment: Yeah, that's right. `freeze` is also used additionally. It's actually `freeze` causes the TypeError.

Comment: @CuiPengFei I edited my answer and included the source code link. Thank you.

Comment: This answer could do with more of the details in the answer (and not in external links). Copy the relevant details into the answer and highlight them using the quote format

Comment: I've added some details (please roll back if you disagree). You'll find you will get much better response from [answers that include as much of the details as possible in the answer itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @Liam Thank you very much for editing and for the advice. I will keep it in mind!