# React props unexpected behavior when using in different ways?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I was developing something and by accident I encountered different behavior of React props.

```
import ChildComponent from "./child";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Parent Component</h1>
      <ChildComponent name="Mike" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const ChildComponent = ({ name }) => {
  name = "John";
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Child Component</h1>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

For the above code the output is **Name : John**. But if I change the code slightly like below:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  props.name = "John";
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Child Component</h1>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <p>{props.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

the output is **Name : Mike**.

Why is this the case & what is the difference between the two?

Comment: IIRC props are *(shallowly)* immutable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44495385/1086398

Comment: @adsy I gone through the question mentioned by you, but still I am not able to understands this behavior.